# How to Apply PCA to one-dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, scikit-learn, pca

I have flatten() X_train and X_test 32* 32 *3
and I want to apply Principal component analysis **(PCA)** to reduce the size of the feature to 150
but it's 1D and it gives me an error

```
x_train,x_test = X_train.flatten(), X_test.flatten()

pca = PCA(n_components=150)
  x_train = pca.fit_transform(x_train)
  x_test = pca.transform(x_test)
```

I get

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead
```

---

```
x_train shape (50000, 32, 32, 3)
, x_test shape (10000, 32, 32, 3)
```

after flatten

```
x_train shape (153600000,)
, x_test shape (30720000,)
```

Comment: If i used reshape (1,-1) I get error ->   ValueError: n_components=150 must be between 0 and min(n_samples, n_features)=1 with svd_solver='full'

Comment: I think you need to read what is PCA. What you are asking has no sense.  "PCA is a conditionality reduction technique and you only have one dimension. What you want to reduce more?

Answer (score 1):

`fit` methods of `PCA` class expect 2-dimesnional arrays in form `(n_samples, n_features)`. And `ValueError` occurs because of applying reshape somewhere inside a method while checking 2D form. Assuming your dataset something like CIFAR-10 (every sample is an image with 3 color channels and size 32 x 32 pixels; 50000 in train set and 10000 test), correct reshape before passing to PCA would be `x_train.reshape(-1, 32 * 32 * 3)`, analogously with `x_test`. That way every sample gets flattened into N-dimensional vector, and on bunch of them PCA makes sense.